# php script to generate url for php api

Tags: php, api, last.fm

i need some help as i am completely novice with php..

I have made a simple script to get an XML tracklist (from an API), then decode what i need and make a ul list with the tracks..

I also need to pull some artist images from a last.fm php script i found recently..

The scripts api is using http adress to get the artist and then bring up the images i found it here https://gist.github.com/iwek/5109952 and the syntax of request is : http://example.com/lastfm.php?artist=Adele

My php code for tracklist is :

```
foreach ($mysongs as $item):
$x = explode(" - ",$item->track);
$artist = $x[0];
$title = $x[1];
echo "<ul>$artist 
$song</ul>\n";
endforeach;
```

Now i need to put inside the foreach the php code to generate the api call url and also include the image that this script outputs.. I am really stuck here guy's !
If anyone has any idea please do tell !

PS: keep in mind that i am really novice with php..
Thank you for your answers

Comment: Your HTML is also wrong. `echo "<ul>";` should come before `foreach($mysongs as $item):`.  Then your echo statement should be more like `echo "<li>$artist - $song</li>";`. Then place `echo '</ul>';` after `endforeach;`

Comment: As for your question, look at the Github link you posted.  Lines 98 - 126.  It's pretty much doing what you're looking for.  You just need to wrap that in your `for` loop.

Comment: @jmbertucci I Just realized it ! I have been looking it for 6 hours, searching the net for any similar and now i saw it... Thank you for mentioning it and correcting my mistakes..

Comment: Glad I could help.  Good luck to you!

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = "http://www.example.com/lasfm.php";
$artist="Adele";
echo "$url?artist=$artist";
```